# select rows from dataframe where any of the columns is higher 0.001

Tags: python, pandas

I would normally write

```
df[ (df.Col1>0.0001) | (df.Col2>0.0001) | (df.Col3>0.0001) ].index
```

to get the labels where the condition holds True. If I have many columns, and say I had a tuple

```
cols = ('Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3')
```

`cols` is a subset of df columns.

Is there a more succinct way of writing the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine [`pandas.DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and list indexing to create a mask for use in indexing.

Note that `cols` has to be a list, not a tuple.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

N = 10
M = 0.8

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Col1':np.random.random(N), 'Col2':np.random.random(N), 
                        'Col3':np.random.random(N), 'Col4':np.random.random(N)})

cols = ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']

mask = (df[cols] > M).any(axis=1)

print(df[mask].index)
# Int64Index([0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7], dtype='int64')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension using 'any' or 'all':

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

In [148]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(25).reshape(5,5), columns=list('abcde'))
In [149]: df
Out[149]:
          a         b         c         d         e
0 -1.484887  2.204350  0.498393  0.003432  0.792417
1 -0.595458  0.850336  0.286450  0.201722  1.699081
2 -0.437681 -0.907156  0.514573 -1.162837 -0.334180
3 -0.160818 -0.384901  0.076484  0.599763  1.923360
4  0.351161  0.519289  1.727934 -1.232707  0.007984
```

Example where you want all the columns in a given row to be greater than -1

```
In [153]: df.iloc[ [row for row in df.index if all(df.loc[row] > -1)], :]
Out[153]:
          a         b         c         d         e
1 -0.595458  0.850336  0.286450  0.201722  1.699081
3 -0.160818 -0.384901  0.076484  0.599763  1.923360
```

Example where you want any the columns in a given row to be greater than -1

```
In [154]: df.iloc[ [row for row in df.index if any(df.loc[row] > -1)], :]
Out[154]:
          a         b         c         d         e
0 -1.484887  2.204350  0.498393  0.003432  0.792417
1 -0.595458  0.850336  0.286450  0.201722  1.699081
2 -0.437681 -0.907156  0.514573 -1.162837 -0.334180
3 -0.160818 -0.384901  0.076484  0.599763  1.923360
4  0.351161  0.519289  1.727934 -1.232707  0.007984
```